# Visual Leak Detector Error message '#include <vld.h>' should appear before '#include <afxwin.h> in file stdafx.h

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, memory-leaks, mfc

Good morning.

I am building an MFC program using Visual Studio 2010.

I want to use the Visual Leak Detector to detect memory leaks in my program.

I retrieved the usage and ran it, but I got into trouble.

First, I placed vld.h after stdafx.h as described in my usage.

So I put this header in MainFrame.cpp (the main program).

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <vld.h>
```

After doing this, after compiling and running, I get an error message.

```
'#include <vld.h>' should appear before '#include <afxwin.h> in file stdafx.h.
```

So I put

```
#include <vld.h>
```

inside stdafx.h like this.

```
#include <vld.h>
#include <afxwin.h>
#include <afxext.h>
#include <afxdisp.h>
```

After doing this, the program is running, but there is no information about the Memory Leak.

How can I solve this problem?

If you do not have enough information, I will add more.

Thank you.

Comment: The best way to detect memory leaks in any MFC app is to run the debug build of the app in the debugger.  You will be informed automatically of any memory leaks. If you use the ' #define new DEBUG_NEW' macro block at the top of each cpp file, you will be informed of the type of the object leaked and the module and line where the memory was allocated.

Comment: @Michaël Roy Thank you for comment! I will do that.

Comment: I forgor to mentiopn that the debugger will report leaks when you exit the your application.  This method works  really well.

Comment: @MichaëlRoy: From my own experience I disagree. There lots of memory leaks escaping to CRT that are reported by VLD.